# Delim Tabs in a string

Tags: c#, split

```
string s = "    1    16    34";
string[] words = s.Split('\t');
foreach (string word in words)
{
   Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

I have a string format as shown above, but when I try to deliminate using the escape tab, it just outputs the exact same string in its original format, why is not removing the tabs?

Comment: Because the string doesn't contain *tab characters*?

Comment: Some editors will turn tab key presses into spaces.  It seems like you've actually got multiple spaces between your tokens instead of tabs.  Try `string s = "\t1\t16\34";` instead.

Comment: `string s = "    1    16    34";` try this : `string s = "\t1\t16\t34";` the original string has spaces in , not tabs

Comment: This string is orginally from a formatted text file, this is one sample. I cannot tell whether they are four spaces or tabs. And am not sure how to delim the whitespaces using Split since it uses chars. I tried that by intentionally adding the escape tabs (which does work btw), but I want to read them exactly as they are.

Comment: You might also want to try `s.Split(new [] {' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.  That will split on spaces and tabs and remove empty entries that would occur between consecutive delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

```
    string[] words = s.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                }
```

I think I fixed it.

It gives me this output.

1

16

34

Which I checked by outputting all 3 in the array to make sure they are separated.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work with my textfile (that contains 100,000 lines) adapting that method I tested.

Answer (score 1):

`Split` on `char[0]` - this will split on all whitespaces.
`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` - will remover empty entries.

```
var words = myStr.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using split without a argument

```
string s = "    1   16  34";
string[] words = s.Split();
foreach (string word in words)
{
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This will split the string by every whitespace, tab.

Comment: That will output blank lines (even once you've corrected the `Console.WriteLine();`)

Answer (score 0):

Paranoidal solution: split on any *white space* (space, tab, non-breaking space etc.)

```
  string s = "    1    16    34";

  string[] words = Regex
    .Matches(s, @"\S+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Regular expressions can well be *overshoot*, but can help out in case of dirty data.